# Retrieve variable name from an HTML site

Tags: javascript, html, apache, filesystemobject

I am trying to retrieve simple javascript variable (which is written to a `File Systems Object`) from a website which is served by an apache host on my ubuntu laptop.

So I have the function that writes the variable set up as follows:

```
        <script type ="text/javascript">
     function WriteToFile(passForm) {

        set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
        set s = fso.CreateTextFile("/home/lex/Downloads/goal.txt", true);
        s.writeline(document.passForm);
        s.Close();
     }
      </script>
```

and the section that takes the user input from the html website is

```
     <div id="bot-right">
        <form onsubmit="WriteToFile(this['goal'].value)">       
           <a align = "left"> <b><Strong>Enter a Goal name</Strong></b></a><br>
            <input type="text" name="goal"> <br>        
            <input type="submit" value="Send Zeus">
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

For some reason, when I type in variable names to the form on the website, the file `goal.txt` gets created in the directory, `/home/lex/Downloads/`, but nothing gets written to it.

I also noticed that when I delete the `goal.txt` file and rewrite the variable from the html website, the file doesn't always get created.

I am not a JavaScript person and I am at a loss as to what I may need to fix this.

My intention is to get the variable written to the text file and have a processing c++ file process the variable.

Would someone be kind enough to lend an insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is just calling the function without parameters and just getting the input value like this:

1. adding and id or a class to your input to get that specific value:

   `document.getElementById('goal').value`

   `document.getElementByClass('goal').value`
2. Or getting the value by name:

   `document.querySelector('[name="goal"]').value;`

**EDIT1**

You could add a console.log to check if the value is beign passed correctly like this:

`var inputValue = document.querySelector('[name="goal"]').value;`

```
console.log(inputValue);
```

And if the value is being passed then the problem is your writeline or in the creation of the document

**EDIT2**

I just tested it and retrieving the value works just fine, so the problem must be in your document writing method, please check this documentation it can help you and i think is a better solution:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: It's still the same. The site doesn't write the goal to the text file. Could there be something I'm missing?